# Apache solr filter based on array values

Tags: solr, solrcloud, solrnet, solr-query-syntax

I have 2 data's which I have mentioned below:

```
{
    id: intro.original
    publicationID: TRENTXWB_EM_R1
    hasBeenModifiedBy: [DAL]
    isModificationFor: null
    text: ... intro ...
}

{
    id: intro.dal
    publicationID: TRENTXWB_EM_R1
    hasBeenModifiedBy: []
    isModificationFor: DAL
    text: ... intro ...
}
```

Need to develop a filter query which checks "hasBeenModifiedBy".If the array contains 'DAL' it has to commit that datset(i.e. igonore the dataset). So, in this case, we have to get the second dataset which doesn't have "DAL" in "hasBeenModified" array.

Please suggest me an approach.

Comment: `q=*:* -hasBeenModifiedBy:DAL` should give you all documents that doesn't have `DAL` in the `hasBeenModifiedBy` field. If this is your only clause, you should be able to leave `*:*` out of the query as well.

Comment: @MatsLindh it is possible to do the same in filter query ?

Comment: Yes, but in that case you have to add the `*:*` explicitly as far as I remember. i.e. `*:* -hasBeenModifiedBy:DAL`